# Clickonce universal publish

Tags: clickonce, publishing

I have published application to network drive like that

```
  \\server\shared_folder
```

Works well, but now I'm interested to copy published binaries to different URL,let's say:

```
  \\server2\shared_folder2
```

But installation fails saying that setup.exe was ran from different location then originally published.

Do you know the way how to just copy those binaries (without rebuilding/publishing to 2nd server) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the location, you have to change the installation URL. The easiest way to edit this is to use mageUI, it is in the deployment manifest (.application file). You'll have to re-sign the manifest as well. (I think MageUI will prompt you for that.)

Comment: Sure, but I'm looking way to just copy it over different location without signing. just copy / paste...